# Maven - execute comand in seperate thread before and after test

Tags: java, maven, testing, jersey, jetty

I have a module in my project that is depentent on a server running for the unit tests to work. The server can be run with the command `mvn jetty:run -f moduleName/pom.xml`. Is there a way to automatically start the server in a new thread, before the test phase starts, and terminate it afterwards? In other words, i want the server to start after running `mvn test` and stop the server again once it moves on to the next module.

I've already tried using JerseyTest, but I am not satisfied with the result because of the complexity of the module and all the different classes that depend on the server.

Comment: is it important it is mvn test? or can you move these tests back in the lifecycle to mvn integration-test? as for this phase there are pre- and post- phases you could add that server startup.

Comment: It would definetely be preferable if it runs with mvn test, but if that is not possible, doing it during integration-test is a viable option.

Comment: I would recommend to take a deep look here: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html and see how to bind jetty-maven-pugin into the life cycle. Also I would suggest to use pre-integration-test phase and post-integration-test phase cause they are for integration tests which the test you are using simply are.